# Static Class/Method Stopping my application

Tags: c#, winforms, static-methods

I am having problems calling a static method from another method.

My static method is in a separate project, but I have checked the references and the using statements and everything seems right.  Below is a simplified version.

The static method

```
namespace Backend
{
    static public class StartUpChecks
    {
        public static void RunAtStart()
        {
            // Calls other static methods and sets application settings
        }
     }
}
```

The Windows Form

```
using Backend;

namespace UI
{
    public partial class mainForm:Form
    {
        public mainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("It Works");
            StartUpChecks.RunAtStart();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program it simply stops.  I have set a breakpoint on the OnLoad event handler but it never gets hit.  If I comment-in the MessageBox and comment-out the method call the event fires and the message box shows.

I have no errors showing in VS.  I tried creating another method, Test(), and moved the StartUpChecks.RunAtStart() into it.  Then I put the Test() call after the MessageBox.  The event fires, the message box shows but it will not move on to the Test() method.

Also in VS when debugging I cannot restart the process and I can't step into/over anything.

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

EDIT---

The full Static Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DataSourceManager;
using UserValidator;

namespace Backend
{
    static public class StartUpChecks
    {
        public static void RunAtStart()
        {
            CheckUserAuthorised();
            CheckUserAdmin();
            SetConnection("myApplication");
        }

        private static void SetConnection(string appName)
        {
            AppControl.Connection = ConnectionSetter.SetConnectionString(appName);
        }

        private static void CheckUserAuthorised()
        {
            UserValidation checkMe = new UserValidation(AppControl.Connection);
            AppControl.UserIsAuthorised = checkMe.UserIsAuthorised();
        }

        private static void CheckUserAdmin()
        {
            UserValidation checkMe = new UserValidation(AppControl.Connection);
            AppControl.UserIsAdmin = checkMe.UserIsAdmin();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What else is in the StartUpChecks class? Is there a static constructor that might be throwing an exception?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Nope, no static constructor.  Do I need one - is that the problem?

Comment: When debugging in this state, if you press Pause (Ctrl+Break) in Visual Studio, which line is highlighted? (Hopefully it's not Application.Run())

Comment: @Slotty, no just an idea I had.

Comment: @Jonathan  - It is Application.Run().  Is that bad?

Comment: can you publish static class code? the issue in the ststic class initialization.

Comment: You might want to show (or explain well) what kind of code is being called within the static method. I don't think that the fact that it is static is the problem. Does it still halt your application if you remove all of the code from the static method and maybe do something simple instead or maybe execute nothing inside of it?

Comment: Application.Run() is just where any WinForms app will pause if it isn't currently running any of your code.  Bad news is that it doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: is your VS debuger configured to handle throw exception instead of unhandled exception?

Comment: @jlafay - I took all the code out of the RunAtStart() Method but it still stops.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to configure VS to handle thrown exceptions:

Main Menu -> Debug -> Exceptions => Set checkbox beside CLR Exceptions in the "Thrown" cell

Other point enable external code debuging

Main menu -> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Uncheck point Just in my code

After this changes try to run your application

Comment: @ Viacheslav - I get a TypeLoadException - "Could not load type 'Backend.StartUpChecks' from assembly 'MyApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'" - Is this something easy to fix?  MSDN Tells me what it is but not what to do with it.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not an idea

Answer (score 1):

There's a nasty bug in the interaction between the operating system and the 64-bit debugger.  It causes exceptions that are raised in the Load event handler (or OnLoad method override) to be swallowed without a diagnostic.

Best way to bypass it is to use Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target = x86.  That's the default for VS2010 and also re-enables Edit + Continue.  Nice.  If running in 64-bit mode is really important then you can trap the exception with Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for Common Language Runtime exceptions.

This bug otherwise doesn't byte in your final program, it only goes wrong when a debugger is attached.

Comment: I have just checked and it is  set to x86.  Good advice though thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the error on AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event. You add this code in your mainform constructor.

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    }

    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //Diagnose the exception here..
    }
```

Additionally, you can try using a live windows client debugging and tracing utility "**[Donsole](http://donsole.codeplex.com/)**" for live tracing.

[image]